# Send notification upon Zabbix active agent shut down

Tags: monitoring, network-monitoring, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I have configured zabbix server with zabbix active agents but I am not able to get notifications when zabbix active agents shut down. I have no issue getting email notifications when active agents reboot or turn on after shut down. But I would like to get notifications as soon as zabbix active agents shut down or in case of network failure in agents side. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually done with items and triggers. If you are using the default templates, this should be already done for you, although the default templates are passive-only.

As a very simple approach, try changing the `agent.ping` item in the template to `Zabbix agent (active)`. Note that this might remove the passive reachability alerting.